# Add one more row

Tags: android-layout

I am Android developer .While clicking plus button i need one more row.

For Ex (Edit contacts We are click plus means added one more row and minus means remove that row.Just give me xml layout and sample coding for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an onClickListener() for the button. Then reference your tableLayout via

```
tblLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
```

then use

```
TableRow = new TableRow(this);    
//Do something with this row
row.setText("...");

//add the row to the tblLayout
tblLayout.addView(row);
```